# Load key invalid format to connect ssh server

Tags: linux, ssh, configuration, passwords

I'm having problems setting an auto-login using ssh, I tried some things that I have seen there but none of them worked for me.

I have my .ssh/config with the host as,

```
Host hostname
   User ...
   HostName ...
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/idKey
```

An I have done for the key to be readable for me only `chmod 600 .ssh/idKey`. But when I do ssh the following error appears,

`Load key "/home/juan/.ssh/idKey": invalid format`

I tested my `idKey` to have diferent formats,

- The raw key,

```
«password»
```

- Also with headers that I found here,

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
«password»
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

or

```
-----BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY-----
«password»
-----END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY-----
```

But the error still appearing, so how I should write the simple .ssh/idKey to have a correct format?

Comment: Is "<password>" a long string of base64 encoded text? How did you create the key?

Comment: Is my normal password, with it I'm registered to the server I'm connecting. Like a few ~15 number+letters string

Comment: SSH keys are encryption keys, not passwords, but they can optionally be encrpyted themselves with a password.